# Spectrum of the operator PAP, with A self-adjoint and P strictly positive

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

Let $A$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator with spectrum $\sigma(A)=\mathbb R$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. Let $P$ be a bounded operator in $\mathcal H$ satisfying $P\ge1$ and
$$
{\rm Domain}(AP)
\equiv\big[\varphi\in\mathcal H:P\varphi\in{\rm Domain}(A)\big]
={\rm Domain}(A).
$$
Finally, suppose that the operator
$$
H:=PAP,\quad{\rm Domain}(H):={\rm Domain}(A),
$$
is self-adjoint in $\mathcal H$.

Question: Can we find conditions on $A$ and $P$ guaranteeing that the spectrum of $H$ is the same of that of $A$; that is, guaranteeing that $\sigma(H)=\sigma(A)=\mathbb R$ ?

Even though operators like $H$ appear in Spectral Theory, I haven't been able to find much information on their spectrum in the literature. I am only aware of the paper:

Hladnik, Milan, Omladic, Matjaz,
Spectrum of the product of operators.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 102 (1988), no. 2, 300–302,

whose results are too general to answer the present question.

Comment: Shouldn't a polar decomposition help here?

Comment: Simplest condition $P = P^{-1}$. (So $P = g(Q)$ for $g$ taking values in $+1, -1$.)    Note, this condition corresponds to preserving eigenvalues & eigenfunctions.      Of course one can imagine many other reasons for the claim to hold ... in the form stated it is just TOO general to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable condition I can think of is that $P = g(A)$ where $g \ge 1$ is a bounded continuous  function on $\mathbb R$.

It is instructive to consider the case where $A$ is the multiplication operator $(A f)(x) = x f(x)$ on $L^2({\mathbb R})$ and $P = g(A)$ for some bounded measurable function $g \ge 1$.  Then $\sigma(PAP)$ is the essential range of $\{ x g(x)^2: x \in {\mathbb R}\}$.  For suitable discontinuous $g$, this could be any closed subset $S$ of the plane that intersects $(-\infty,N)$, $(-1/N,0)$, $(0,1/N)$ and $(N,\infty)$ for all $N$.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the example I have in mind the operators $A$ and $P$ do not commute.

The typical situation would be the one where $A$ is the operator of differentiation $(Af):=-if'(x)$ in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $P=g(X)$ with a bounded $C^1$ function $g\ge1$ and $X$ the multiplication operator $(Xf):=xf(x)$ in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Have you looked at the results on perturbation of continuous spectrum in Kato, "Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators"?  

Comment: I guess that Kato's book is indeed the best we can get. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A way to prove that the spectrum are the same, since they are equal to $\mathbb{R}$, is to prove that they have the same essential spectrum. To do so, an easy way is to ensure that $(H+i)^{-1}- (A+i)^{-1}$ is compact.

By using the resolvent formula, one sees that it is enough to suppose that 
$H - A$ is compact from $D(A)$ to $D(A)^*$ [recall that $H$ and $A$ have the same domain by hypothesis]. Here I used the Riesz isomorphism to identify $\mathcal{H}$ with its antidual.

Finally, since $H-A= (1-P)A + PA(1-P)$ you can suppose for instance 
$P\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{D}(A))$ (which implies $P\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{D}(A)^*)$ by duality)  and $1-P\in \mathcal{K}(\mathcal{D}(A), \mathcal{H})$ (which implies $1-P\in \mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{D}(A)^*)$ by duality).